# Error with Ruby Twitter API

Tags: ruby, twitter

I am getting an error with a Ruby script using the 'twitter' gem.  The part of my script that is producing the error is

```
require 'twitter'
require 'net/http'
require 'json'

#### Get your twitter keys & secrets:
#### https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/tokens-devtwittercom
Twitter.configure do |config|
  config.consumer_key = 'xxxxxxx'
  config.consumer_secret = 'xxxxxxx'
  config.oauth_token = 'xxxxxx'
  config.oauth_token_secret = 'xxxxxxx'
end
```

The error says `undefined method 'configure' for Twitter:Module (NoMethodError)`
However the 'twitter' and 'json' gems are both in my gemfile so I'm not sure why this method would be undefined.

Comment: what version of the gem are you using?
Its stated in the documentation that configuration is done through the Twitter::REST::Client.new method

Comment: In my Gemfile.lock file it says 'twitter (5.0.0)'

Comment: follow the documentation from here: https://github.com/sferik/twitter

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are doing it the "old" way. Starting in Version 5, global configuration is not longer available. So, basically you need to pass the config parameters when you initialize a client.

For example:

```
client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
  config.consumer_key        = "YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY"
  config.consumer_secret     = "YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET"
  config.access_token        = "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN"
  config.access_token_secret = "YOUR_ACCESS_SECRET"
end
```

And then just use that client to do queries, such as:

```
client.sample do |tweet|
  puts tweet.text
end
```

For more information just refer to [Sferik's Twitter Gem](https://github.com/sferik/twitter)

Comment: If I wanted to get a list of the most recent 4 tweets, how would I do this?  I can't access client in any of the controllers as 'client' gets me a NameError -- this documentation is frustrating me.  They don't display any controller code...