# Twitter handler (sensu and ruby) troubleshooting

Tags: ruby, debugging, twitter, handler, sensu

I'm trying to get Sensu twitter-handler working on my environment. The issue is that I'm not getting any errors on screen or logs when I cat a .json event into the twitter-handler and, the tweets are not being shown on the linked account.

Here're are my config files:

https://gist.github.com/Mariano-gon/8648427

https://gist.github.com/Mariano-gon/8648455

https://gist.github.com/Mariano-gon/8648489

This is the output I get:

https://gist.github.com/Mariano-gon/8648480

One important note is that in sensu-api.log the request are being recieved:

https://gist.github.com/Mariano-gon/8673758

So, my question is: is there a way to troubleshoot this issue? Any way to debug the handler.rb? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working! Thing was the new 'twitter' gem (in my case v5.6) won't work with the code as it was written. I needed to follow this great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20247712/error-with-ruby-twitter-api) and this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528101/ssl-connect-returned-1-errno-0-state-sslv3-read-server-certificate-b-certificat) too. Was just a matter of sintaxis (as usual).
Thanks!