# Tweet with twitter gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter

The documentation says

```
config = Twitter.configure do |config|
  config.consumer_key = 'YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY'
  config.consumer_secret = 'YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET'
  config.oauth_token = 'YOUR_OAUTH_TOKEN'
  config.oauth_token_secret = 'YOUR_OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET'
end
```

and

```
client.update('Hello, from Twitter Gem!')
```

But where do I put them? (also, why do documentation assume everyone knows where to put things?)

---

What is one valid design for doing this

For example, I have a twitter button on a post. When the twitter button is clicked, I want it to tweet that post (nevermind about handling shortening the post).

Should i put the tweeting `client.update('Hello, from Twitter Gem!')` in an action of a newly created twitter controller?

Or make it a button that calls a javascript file with that tweeting code in it?

I just need one valid way of getting the tweeting button to be functional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used the following setup:

config/initializers/twitter.rb

```
$twitter = Twitter.configure do |config|
  config.consumer_key = 'YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY'
  config.consumer_secret = 'YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET'
  config.oauth_token = 'YOUR_OAUTH_TOKEN'
  config.oauth_token_secret = 'YOUR_OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET'
end
```

Then you can reference the `$twitter` variable in a controller of your choosing. Your view can post a message to the controller, you can do any preprocessing (if needed), and then call `$twitter.update(message)`

I like this setup because it allows me to access my configured twitter client from wherever I need it.

Comment: what's the difference between a variable with `$` and without?

Comment: Will it tweet as the owner of the app, or will it prompt anyone anyone to log into their twitter account and tweet it as their own?

Comment: Without the $ would be a regular local variable. We need it available in a scope that can be seen by your controller. As for the tweet, it would go out as the owner. Specifically, the account that generated the keys.

Comment: so you're referring to the second set of keys, the owner of the app. The first set of keys is just for the app to connect to twitter and view stuff. What I really need is for users that are logged into their twitter accounts to click a button on my app, and tweet content from my app via their twitter account. Just like fmylife.com does

Comment: The twitter gem page says global variables are not threadsafe.

Comment: so it's the "your oauth token" that allows me to tweet as my twitter account linked to the app. Without that, i would not be able to use the `.update` function successfully?

Comment: I see. Based on those requirements, you need to configure a Twitter client for the user each time he or she tweets. Are you storing the user's oath tokens?

Comment: This tutorial might help you: http://richonrails.com/articles/sending-a-tweet-to-twitter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61535/discussion-between-gwho-and-danielm).

Answer (score 0):

Although the question was about file paths, and @danielM is correct, the code is outdated. This was the config setup method youll need to call: [Error with Ruby Twitter API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20247712/error-with-ruby-twitter-api)